# Transform a UART into a USART with twice as many channels?

Tags: uart, serial, communication, digital-communications

I need to provide reliably DAT and CLK lines to a component from a UART - the 16C554. Is it possible to write twice as many bits in an adjacent channel of the UART, alternating between 0 and 1, and sent at twice the datarate of the data channel, to synthesize a reliable clock signal?

The baudrate is around 6Mbps.

Otherwise, any idea?

Comment: No, the 16C550 has only one channel, and it can go up to 3 Mbps. I think you have an XY problem - please describe the X what you are trying to do, instead of asking how to do Y which you think will solve X.

Comment: I don't understand the difference you're assigning between UART and USART, and I'm not sure it's correct.  It *feels like* you're trying to do CLOCK RECOVERY from the UART data.  This is a relatively old idea, but certainly doable.  Search on Clock Recovery, maybe adding UART as a term

Comment: It looks like a phase locked loop is one tool in the toolbox.

Comment: I don't see how I can do clock recovery (which I had already looked into) on a signal which may have two zeros or two ones in a row with no way to tell which is which. Or am I missing something?
@Justme: what I am trying to do is the first line of my question. Is there anything I should clarify?

Comment: @user42875 Yes, if you know what the component is, share the information. How would these devices be connected together, via direct TTL/CMOS pins or via RS232 transceiver, or how? What controls the 16C550? The 16C550 does have TX and RX clock pins but are they available to you?

Comment: It's a cubesat S-band transmitter from ISIS Space - it just says LVDS input, and after talking with the supplier they say it's via DAT+/- and CLK+/- interface. The 16C550 is controlled by a raspberry PI. I do have access to the TX and RX pins, why? Is it possible to use part of a SPI transceiver to send whatever we want through the MOSI line?

Comment: @Justme: Oh, and sorry I forgot to answer: it's a 16C554, so it's got 4 channels - my mistake

Comment: "Is it possible to use part of a SPI transceiver to send whatever we want through the MOSI line?" - Yes. If you have SPI then doing this would be by far the easiest solution.

Comment: @user42875 Now that it is known that the device is a high speed RF link with LVDS input, is there something else we should know? That device is likely to require constant data stream with a constant clock for transmission, and using UART for the serialization would be a bottleneck, if even compatible if it needs some protocol or framing which is not UART compatible. What protocol does the LVDS input require? How is the 16C554 even controlled by RPi, is there a bus for it, or is it on bit-banged GPIO?

Comment: https://protocol-debug.com/2017/02/01/beginners-guide-to-clock-data-recovery/  -- a combo of frequency recovery and phase aligning techniques.  This is what clock recovery is.  There are already auto-detection protocols for baud rate.

Comment: http://pallen.ece.gatech.edu/Academic/ECE_6440/Summer_2003/L200-CDR-I(2UP).pdf